# Running a node.js app created on windows on a mac

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, npm

I am working on one of my first node.js projects and discovered a problem i don't know how to solve. When i try to start my node.js server the following error shows up in the terminal:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: dlopen(/Users/elincorovic/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-PersoÌnlich/programming/projects/js/Wordsmith/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/elincorovic/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-PersoÌnlich/programming/projects/js/Wordsmith/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node' (not a mach-o file)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1183:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/elincorovic/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Persönlich/programming/projects/js/Wordsmith/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this and what to look out for when developing the same node.js app on two different operating systems?

I tried deleting and reinstalling the packages and it worked but do you really have to do this every time you start developing on another operating system?

Comment: *created on windows on a mac*, no you must rebuild dependencies which use bindings (bcrypt, webpack, sass, sharpjs, etc) for the OS and CPU architecture its run on, you cant pass around node_modules say built on windows and it work on linux or macos and visa-versa

Comment: Ok i see, do you have any good ressources on how to rebuild dependencies? And thanks for the answer

Comment: `rm node_modules -Rf && npm i`